# google vision API in python using for loop for uploading images in different folders

Tags: python, vision-api

```
`client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
img = files.upload()
path = "01 happy faces.jpg"
with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
  content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
print("labels (and confidence score):")
print("=" * 79)
for label in response.label_annotations:
  print(f'{label.description} ({label.score*100.:.2f}%)')
```

`I have some images in different folders and I am trying to write a Python code analyze the images

how can I use a for loop?